# Are there any interactive shells for Windows Script Host environment

Tags: shell, wsh

As the title suggests, I am looking for a Python like interactive shell for Windows Script Host. I want to analyze for example, the object that is returned by `GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_process")`. Currently I need to search on Google and refer to the online documentation. It will be far easier if I could just inspect the object for properties and methods, much like Python provides. I tried to install [ActiveScript Shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/activescript-shell/9nblggh532gb) which was promising, but it refuses to run and the main website of the application is no longer up.

Comment: It seems like you could need to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the section named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `software tools commonly used by programmers`. I think this is covered in that.

Comment: And at the same time "Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow". This question is better suited for [the Software recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour).